# Traversal inside another traversal arangodb

Tags: javascript, traversal, arangodb, foxx

I was wondering if it is possible/recommend to perform an traversal inside the `config.visitor` of another traversal in Foxx? Would be there any possible lockings/conflicts?

For side info, my task is to traverse between group of nodes. And in order to determine a group of node should be traversed or not, I first need to traverse them in order to generate some aggregated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack [AQL traversals](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html) in several iterations.

The old traversal API can easily become resource bound by the V8 engine, thus AQL-Traversals should be prefered.